# Ubuntu mysql crashes - InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, crash, innodb

So my mysql service crashed today on my ubuntu droplet server which has 20gb storage and 512mb memory, it seems to be because of fail to allocate memory for mysql. 
I've read that I could increase/decrease memory of innodb_buffer_pool_size, but would that solve the problem? What would be the best option to keep the mysql service from crashing?

```
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-06-19 06:47:18 23040 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not allocate to much memory at all. So MySQL allocates memory for the core and for each connection.

So you can run these queries find find the total memory amount

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_buffer_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'thread_stack';
SET @kilo_bytes = 1024;
SET @mega_bytes = @kilo_bytes * 1024;
SET @giga_bytes = @mega_bytes * 1024;
SET @innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2 * @giga_bytes;
SET @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16 * @mega_bytes;
SET @innodb_log_buffer_size = 8 * @mega_bytes;
SET @thread_stack = 192 * @kilo_bytes;
SELECT
( @@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@tmp_table_size
+ @innodb_buffer_pool_size + @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
+ @innodb_log_buffer_size
+ @@max_connections * (
@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size
+ @@join_buffer_size + @@binlog_cache_size + @thread_stack
) ) / @giga_bytes AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
```

Comment: Why did the mysql service fail in first place then? And how much memory should I allocate and why would less memory make it more stable?

Answer (score 0):

`my.cnf` contains the settings for various things.  512MB of RAM is *tiny*.  That needs to hold the OS, MySQL code, and lots of other things.  Asking for 128MB for the buffer_pool was simply too much.  Try `50M`.  Probably other things should be lowered in `my.cnf`, too.  Show us the entire my.cnf for further discussion.